# PLL Clock distribution

Tags: clock, pll

I am generating 40MHz clock using [ADF4106](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADF4106-EP.pdf) PLL Frequency Synthesizer with VCO [CVCO55CL-0038-0042](https://www.crystek.com/microwave/admin/webapps/welcome/files/vco/CVCO55CL-0038-0042.pdf). I am using this 40MHz generated frequency for distribution using [ADCLK846](https://www.crystek.com/microwave/admin/webapps/welcome/files/vco/CVCO55CL-0038-0042.pdf). Output power from PLL is -3.5dBm. When I feed this into the Fanout buffer I am getting -11dBM of power level but the signal is the same as input, I am facing only a problem with power level.

So my questions are:-

1. Is my PLL output power level is sufficient for driving fanout buffer.
2. Can I use ADCLK846 for clock distribution with a low input power level signal?

Any suggestions would be helpful.